# How to run an android emulator, on a different computer than the one im runing expo on

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, expo

im starting my first ever project on react native and i was wondering if it was possible for me to run expo on one computer and the android emulator on a different one. I know its possible to run it if i publish the app on expo, but the problem with that method is that each time i make a change to the code, i need to republish the app in order to see a difference, i want the emulator to change immediately like it does when i run the emulator on the same computer as im running expo.
Is that possible? And if so, how do i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after like 5 mins of ACTUALLY using my brain, i decided to try and download expo on the emulator, after i did i went to the expo client and sent the link of the project to my email, then i opened the expo app on the emulator and pasted that same link i sent to my email, now everything is working and the app is refreshing immediately after i make a change to the code.
Hope someone finds this useful.

Comment: How did you download expo on the emulator? I'm not seeing google playstore on any of the available images.