# how to download playstore on android emulator

Tags: android-studio, expo

The actual problem I'm trying to solve is running the expo server on one machine and the android simulator on another as described and answered here:

[How to run an android emulator, on a different computer than the one im runing expo on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61935685/how-to-run-an-android-emulator-on-a-different-computer-than-the-one-im-runing-e/61936046#comment136118148_61936046)

The the solution requires me to manually install expo on the android simulator. However, there is no playstore on any pre-defined image so I'm unable to install expo.